# BeanMap access nested properties

Tags: java, javabeans

When I have a POJO like this:

```
public class Person{
String name;
Address a;
//getters and setters
}
```

When I do, `new BeanMap(new Person())`, how can I retrieve properties of the address class later from the Beanmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

map.get("a.streetName");

Answer (score 1):

I think it is done as:

```
BeanMap map = new BeanMap(new Person());
map.get("address.someProperty");
```

Comment: Did you read the question properly before indulging in sarcasm? If you were not being sarcastic, apologies.